# Node : response.sendFile from server side

Tags: node.js, express

Hey I am very new to Node.js. I want to send an index.html file in public folder to the client side. How can I do this.

My code is given below. This code is in `userroutes.js` in routes folder :

```
router.get('/dashboard',(req,response)=>{
 if(req){

 /*if user wants to jump on dashboard without 
   login then check for request's session
 */
 /* if session exists then redirect to dashboard*/
 if(req.session.userid!=undefined){
   response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dashboard.html'));
 }

 /*if session does not exists then redirect to index.html*/
 else{
   response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'))
 }
}
});
```

And my directory structure is :

[click this link too see my directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bm2i.png)

Now when I tried this code it is throwing an error that

> "index.html" module is not found

**How can I send the index.html file to the client from the server side ?**

Comment: if you're using `path.join` you should not be concatenating strings. Use `path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')` in your second call, for example. Also, what do you want to achieve with that `if (req) {...}`??? that's always true, `req` is always present and not null...

Comment: Sir I am getting this type of error : **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'routespublic\index.html**

Comment: could I use  `app.use(express.static("index.html"));`